# How to find unique occurances that match several conditions

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a df:

```
df
                           These Years are present Runlength  YearSpan                      Company
1                                             1920         1 1920-1920 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 122
2               1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1975        56 1920-1975 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 123
3                     1920  1929  1937  1952  1960        41 1920-1960 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 125
4               1920  1929  1937  1952  1966  1969        50 1920-1969 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 124
5                                             1920         1 1920-1920 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 110
65  1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975        56 1920-1975           Billeruds AB - 103
66                          1920  1937  1952  1960        41 1920-1960           Billeruds AB - 113
67  1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975        56 1920-1975           Billeruds AB - 105
68                                      1920  1937        18 1920-1937           Billeruds AB - 100
69        1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969        50 1920-1969            Billeruds AB - 99
70                                            1920         1 1920-1920            Billeruds AB - 96
250                                           1929         1 1929-1929       AB Nykvarns Bruk - 351
251             1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969        41 1929-1969       AB Nykvarns Bruk - 370
252                                           1929         1 1929-1929               AB Ohs B - 102
253                                           1929         1 1929-1929              AB Papyrus - 38
254                                           1929         1 1929-1929         AB Robertsfors - 302
255             1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969        41 1929-1969         AB Rottneros B - 285
590                               1966  1969  1975        10 1966-1975                   SIAB - 340
591                                     1966  1969         4 1966-1969                   SIAB - 342
592                               1966  1969  1975        10 1966-1975             Skånes C AB - 53
593                               1966  1969  1975        10 1966-1975       Stora Kopparberg - 355
594                               1966  1969  1975        10 1966-1975       Stora Kopparberg - 356
595                               1966  1969  1975        10 1966-1975   Svenska Cellulosa AB - 305
```

`df` is a summary table and I want to find the length of how many observations there is between the years. In example, I want to find how many observations are present between years 1920-1929, where years 1920 and 1929 are included. So, I want to find the length of unique observations where `YearSpan` column in `df` starts with either year 1920 or 1929, and ends with either year 1920 or year 1929.

I thought of something like:

```
unique(grep("^1920",df[,"YearSpan"])+grep("^1929",df[,"YearSpan"])+grep("1920$",df[,"YearSpan"])+grep("1929$",df[,"YearSpan"]))
```

But that is obviously wrong...Any suggestions?:)

```
dput(df)

structure(list(`These Years are present` = structure(c(1L, 10L, 
5L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 26L, 8L, 24L, 7L, 1L, 36L, 41L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
41L, 92L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L), .Label = c("1920", "1920  1929", 
"1920  1929  1937", "1920  1929  1937  1952", "1920  1929  1937  1952  1960", 
"1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1966", "1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969", 
"1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975", "1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1969", 
"1920  1929  1937  1952  1960  1975", "1920  1929  1937  1952  1966  1969", 
"1920  1929  1937  1952  1966  1975", "1920  1929  1937  1960", 
"1920  1929  1937  1960  1966", "1920  1929  1937  1960  1969", 
"1920  1929  1937  1969  1975", "1920  1929  1937  1975", "1920  1929  1952", 
"1920  1929  1952  1960", "1920  1929  1952  1960  1966", "1920  1929  1952  1960  1966  1969", 
"1920  1929  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975", "1920  1929  1952  1960  1966  1975", 
"1920  1937", "1920  1937  1952", "1920  1937  1952  1960", "1920  1937  1952  1960  1966", 
"1920  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969", "1920  1937  1952  1960  1975", 
"1920  1937  1960", "1920  1937  1966  1969", "1920  1952", "1920  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975", 
"1920  1960  1966  1969  1975", "1920  1975", "1929", "1929  1937", 
"1929  1937  1952", "1929  1937  1952  1960", "1929  1937  1952  1960  1966", 
"1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969", "1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975", 
"1929  1937  1952  1960  1966  1975", "1929  1937  1952  1966", 
"1929  1937  1952  1966  1969", "1929  1937  1952  1966  1969  1975", 
"1929  1937  1952  1966  1975", "1929  1937  1960", "1929  1937  1960  1966  1969", 
"1929  1937  1960  1966  1975", "1929  1952", "1929  1952  1960  1966", 
"1929  1960", "1929  1960  1966  1969", "1929  1966  1969", "1937", 
"1937  1952", "1937  1952  1960", "1937  1952  1960  1966", "1937  1952  1960  1966  1969", 
"1937  1952  1960  1966  1969  1975", "1937  1952  1960  1966  1975", 
"1937  1952  1960  1969", "1937  1952  1975", "1937  1960", "1937  1960  1966", 
"1937  1960  1966  1969", "1937  1960  1966  1969  1975", "1937  1966  1969  1975", 
"1937  1969", "1952", "1952  1960", "1952  1960  1966", "1952  1960  1966  1969", 
"1952  1960  1966  1969  1975", "1952  1960  1966  1975", "1952  1960  1969", 
"1952  1960  1969  1975", "1952  1960  1975", "1952  1966  1969", 
"1952  1966  1969  1975", "1952  1969  1975", "1952  1975", "1960", 
"1960  1966", "1960  1966  1969", "1960  1966  1969  1975", "1960  1966  1975", 
"1960  1969", "1966", "1966  1969", "1966  1969  1975", "1966  1975", 
"1969", "1969  1975", "1975"), class = "factor"), Runlength = c(1, 
56, 41, 50, 1, 56, 41, 56, 18, 50, 1, 1, 41, 1, 1, 1, 41, 10, 
4, 10, 10, 10, 10), YearSpan = structure(c(1L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 
8L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L), .Label = c("1920-1920", "1920-1929", "1920-1937", 
"1920-1952", "1920-1960", "1920-1966", "1920-1969", "1920-1975", 
"1929-1929", "1929-1937", "1929-1952", "1929-1960", "1929-1966", 
"1929-1969", "1929-1975", "1937-1937", "1937-1952", "1937-1960", 
"1937-1966", "1937-1969", "1937-1975", "1952-1952", "1952-1960", 
"1952-1966", "1952-1969", "1952-1975", "1960-1960", "1960-1966", 
"1960-1969", "1960-1975", "1966-1966", "1966-1969", "1966-1975", 
"1969-1969", "1969-1975", "1975-1975"), class = "factor"), Company = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 186L, 196L, 188L, 183L, 215L, 213L, 77L, 78L, 
79L, 93L, 96L, 101L, 562L, 564L, 567L, 595L, 596L, 637L), .Label = c("AB Billingsfors-Långed - 110", 
"AB Billingsfors-Långed - 122", "AB Billingsfors-Långed - 123", 
"AB Billingsfors-Långed - 124", "AB Billingsfors-Långed - 125", 
"AB Billingsfors-Långed - 126", "AB Billingsfors-Långed - 127", 
"AB Billingsfors-Långed - 128", "AB Billingsfors-Långed - 130", 
"AB Billingsfors-Långed - 131", "AB Billingsfors-Långed - 246", 
"AB Brusafors -Hfors - 143", "AB Brusafors -Hfors - 15", "AB Brusafors -Hfors - 183", 
"AB Brusafors -Hfors - 210", "AB Brusafors -Hfors - 234", "AB Brusafors -Hfors - 236", 
"AB Brusafors -Hfors - 237", "AB Brusafors -Hfors - 24", "AB Brusafors -Hfors - 34", 
"AB Brusafors -Hfors - 350", "AB Bökholms Sulfitfabrik - 100", 
"AB Bökholms Sulfitfabrik - 196", "AB Eda Bruk - 75", "AB Eda Bruk - 76", 
"AB Ellingeverken - 12", "AB Emsfors B - 337", "AB Emsfors B - 341", 
"AB Finsjö PB - 13", "AB Finsjö PB - 14", "AB Fors B - 216", 
"AB Fors B - 367", "AB Göteborg-Dals PB - 153", "AB Göteborg-Dals PB - 154", 
"AB Göteborg-Dals PB - 155", "AB Göteborg-Dals PB - 156", "AB Högfors - 158", 
"AB Högfors - 185", "AB Högfors - 294", "AB Iggesunds B - 186", 
"AB Iggesunds B - 187", "AB Iggesunds B - 188", "AB Iggesunds B - 189", 
"AB Iggesunds B - 190", "AB Iggesunds B - 191", "AB Iggesunds B - 357", 
"AB Iggesunds B - 8", "AB Industripapp - 362", "AB Klippans FinpB - 120", 
"AB Klippans FinpB - 196", "AB Klippans FinpB - 197", "AB Klippans FinpB - 199", 
"AB Klippans FinpB - 200", "AB Klippans FinpB - 201", "AB Klippans FinpB - 202", 
"AB Klippans FinpB - 203", "AB Klippans FinpB - 206", "AB Klippans FinpB - 210", 
"AB Klippans FinpB - 268", "AB Klippans FinpB - 269", "AB Klippans FinpB - 333", 
"AB Klippans FinpB - 337", "AB Klippans FinpB - 341", "AB Klippans FinpB - 54", 
"AB Klippans FinpB - 55", "AB Klippans FinpB - 56", "AB Konstläderf - 366", 
"AB Laxå PB - 227", "AB Laxå PB - 252", "AB Mariedals B - 229", 
"AB Mölnbacka-Trysil - 132", "AB Mölnbacka-Trysil - 379", "AB Mölnbacka-Trysil - 380", 
"AB Nol-Tingstad - 366", "AB Nykvarns Bruk - 147", "AB Nykvarns Bruk - 262", 
"AB Nykvarns Bruk - 351", "AB Nykvarns Bruk - 370", "AB Ohs B - 102", 
"AB Ohs B - 104", "AB Ohs B - 114", "AB Papyrus - 158", "AB Papyrus - 162", 
"AB Papyrus - 191", "AB Papyrus - 254", "AB Papyrus - 278", "AB Papyrus - 279", 
"AB Papyrus - 280", "AB Papyrus - 308", "AB Papyrus - 372", "AB Papyrus - 373", 
"AB Papyrus - 374", "AB Papyrus - 38", "AB Robertsfors - 169", 
"AB Robertsfors - 242", "AB Robertsfors - 302", "AB Rottneros B - 124", 
"AB Rottneros B - 191", "AB Rottneros B - 283", "AB Rottneros B - 284", 
"AB Rottneros B - 285", "AB Rottneros B - 286", "AB Rottneros B - 287", 
"AB Rottneros B - 288", "AB Rottneros B - 289", "AB Rottneros B - 290", 
"AB Scharins Söner - 231", "AB Scharins Söner - 277", "AB Scharins Söner - 31", 
"AB Scharins Söner - 323", "AB Scharins Söner - 324", "AB Scharins Söner - 329", 
"AB Scharins Söner - 330", "AB Scharins Söner - 332", "AB Scharins Söner - 36", 
"AB Skellefteå TMF - 329", "AB Statens skogsindustrier - 175", 
"AB Statens skogsindustrier - 20", "AB Statens skogsindustrier - 78", 
"AB Statens skogsindustrier - 80", "AB Statens skogsindustrier - 81", 
"AB Statens skogsindustrier - 82", "AB Statens skogsindustrier - 83", 
"AB Statens skogsindustrier - 84", "AB Statens skogsindustrier - 85", 
"AB Sture Ljungdahl - 227", "AB Sture Ljungdahl - 228", "AB Sundhagsfors B - 191", 
"AB Sundhagsfors B - 333", "AB Sundhagsfors B - 64", "AB Svensk Papp - 197", 
"AB Svensk Papp - 278", "AB Svensk Papp - 46", "AB Svensk Papp - 55", 
"AB Svensk Papp - 56", "AB Svensk Papp - 59", "AB Tegefors Verk - 219", 
"AB Tegefors Verk - 220", "AB Tegefors Verk - 267", "AB Thurbo - 216", 
"AB Tollare PB - 193", "AB Tollare PB - 269", "AB Tollare PB - 333", 
"AB Tollare PB - 65", "AB Tollare PB - 66", "AB Träkol - 185", 
"AB Träkol - 259", "AB Träkol - 70", "AB Tumba B - 67", "AB Tumba B - 68", 
"AB Tärefors S - 120", "AB Tärefors S - 47", "AB Umeå TMF-ER - 330", 
"AB Upperuds TMF - 71", "AB Upperuds TMF - 77", "AB Walltex - 47", 
"AB Walltex - 71", "AB Walltex - 77", "AB Vaplans TS - 139", 
"AB Ytterstfors-Munks - 294", "AB Ytterstfors-Munks - 295", "AB Östanå PB - 203", 
"AB Östanå PB - 204", "AB Östrands SFA - 301", "AdolfsForss AB - 1", 
"Alstermo B AB - 2", "Alstermo B AB - 3", "Alstermo B AB - 4", 
"Ankarsviks Å AB - 324", "Ankarsviks Å AB - 332", "Bengtsfors Sulfit AB - 10", 
"BergForss AB - 5", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 188", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 20", 
"Bergvik o Ala N AB - 218", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 296", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 308", 
"Bergvik o Ala N AB - 347", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 6", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 7", 
"Bergvik o Ala N AB - 8", "Bergvik o Ala N AB - 9", "Billeruds AB - 100", 
"Billeruds AB - 101", "Billeruds AB - 102", "Billeruds AB - 103", 
"Billeruds AB - 104", "Billeruds AB - 105", "Billeruds AB - 106", 
"Billeruds AB - 107", "Billeruds AB - 108", "Billeruds AB - 109", 
"Billeruds AB - 110", "Billeruds AB - 111", "Billeruds AB - 112", 
"Billeruds AB - 113", "Billeruds AB - 127", "Billeruds AB - 134", 
"Billeruds AB - 137", "Billeruds AB - 196", "Billeruds AB - 250", 
"Billeruds AB - 313", "Billeruds AB - 338", "Billeruds AB - 349", 
"Billeruds AB - 87", "Billeruds AB - 88", "Billeruds AB - 89", 
"Billeruds AB - 90", "Billeruds AB - 91", "Billeruds AB - 92", 
"Billeruds AB - 94", "Billeruds AB - 95", "Billeruds AB - 96", 
"Billeruds AB - 98", "Billeruds AB - 99", "Björknäs N S AB - 185", 
"Björknäs N S AB - 307", "Björkå AB - 11", "Björkå AB - 231", 
"Bowaters svenska Trämassefabriker - 312", "Bowaters svenska Trämassefabriker - 329", 
"Bowaters svenska Trämassefabriker - 330", "Bowaters svenska Trämassefabriker - 331", 
"Bure AB - 11", "Bure AB - 231", "Bure AB - 329", "Byhamns C AB - 219", 
"Byhamns C AB - 302", "Bäckhammars Bruk - 131", "Bäckhammars Bruk - 132", 
"Bäckhammars Bruk - 133", "Bäckhammars Bruk - 379", "Djupafors Fabriks AB - 186", 
"Djupafors Fabriks AB - 191", "Djupafors Fabriks AB - 192", "Djupafors Fabriks AB - 193", 
"Djupafors Fabriks AB - 30", "Djupafors Fabriks AB - 46", "Djupafors Fabriks AB - 56", 
"Dynäs AB - 248", "Dynäs AB - 266", "Dynäs AB - 270", "Dynäs AB - 79", 
"Eds Cellulosaf-s AB - 134", "Eds Cellulosaf-s AB - 96", "Fengersfors B AB - 135", 
"Fengersfors B AB - 136", "Figeholms B - 16", "Figeholms B - 17", 
"Fiskeby AB - 138", "Fiskeby AB - 139", "Fiskeby AB - 141", "Fiskeby AB - 142", 
"Fiskeby AB - 143", "Fiskeby AB - 144", "Fiskeby AB - 145", "Fiskeby AB - 146", 
"Fiskeby AB - 147", "Fiskeby AB - 148", "Fiskeby AB - 149", "Fiskeby AB - 150", 
"Fiskeby AB - 193", "Fiskeby AB - 236", "Fiskeby AB - 298", "Fiskeby AB - 308", 
"Fiskeby AB - 350", "Fiskeby AB - 359", "Fiskeby AB - 361", "Fiskeby AB - 362", 
"Fiskeby AB - 370", "Fiskeby AB - 69", "Fiskeby AB - 97", "Forsmarks CF - 151", 
"Forss AB - 168", "Forss AB - 266", "Forss AB - 271", "Forss AB - 272", 
"Forss AB - 346", "Forsså Bruks AB - 15", "Forsså Bruks AB - 16", 
"Forsså Bruks AB - 234", "Forsså Bruks AB - 27", "Forsså Bruks AB - 29", 
"Forsviks AB - 152", "Fridafors Fabriks AB - 193", "Fridafors Fabriks AB - 333", 
"Fridafors Fabriks AB - 342", "Fridafors Fabriks AB - 64", "Gamlestadens PB AB - 153", 
"Graningeverkens AB - 158", "Graningeverkens AB - 159", "Graningeverkens AB - 185", 
"Graningeverkens AB - 278", "Gransholms AB - 228", "Grycksbo PB AB - 349", 
"Grycksbo PB AB - 350", "Grycksbo PB AB - 351", "Gustafsfors F-ERS AB - 129", 
"Gustafsfors F-ERS AB - 130", "Gustafsfors F-ERS AB - 131", "Gustafsfors F-ERS AB - 349", 
"Göteborgs Handelsbank - 374", "Göteborgs PB AB - 154", "Heffners AB - 46", 
"Hellefors B AB - 118", "Hellefors B AB - 119", "Hellefors B AB - 120", 
"Hellefors B AB - 121", "Hellefors B AB - 197", "Hellefors B AB - 86", 
"HissmoForss AB - 115", "HissmoForss AB - 168", "HissmoForss AB - 169", 
"HissmoForss AB - 267", "Hjälmare Ko Slussv A - 18", "Holmens B o F AB - 130", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 160", "Holmens B o F AB - 161", "Holmens B o F AB - 162", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 164", "Holmens B o F AB - 166", "Holmens B o F AB - 167", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 168", "Holmens B o F AB - 169", "Holmens B o F AB - 170", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 171", "Holmens B o F AB - 172", "Holmens B o F AB - 174", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 176", "Holmens B o F AB - 230", "Holmens B o F AB - 242", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 267", "Holmens B o F AB - 272", "Holmens B o F AB - 302", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 328", "Holmens B o F AB - 346", "Holmens B o F AB - 361", 
"Holmens B o F AB - 73", "Holmens B o F AB - 83", "Holmsunds AB - 222", 
"Holmsunds AB - 312", "Hyltebruks AB - 178", "Hyltebruks AB - 179", 
"Hyltebruks AB - 180", "Hyltebruks AB - 181", "Hyltebruks AB - 272", 
"Hyltebruks AB - 304", "Håvreströms AB - 206", "Håvreströms AB - 207", 
"Håvreströms AB - 208", "Håvreströms AB - 250", "Håvreströms AB - 272", 
"Håvreströms AB - 361", "Högbroforsens Ind AB - 185", "Högbroforsens Ind AB - 259", 
"Inlands AB - 140", "Inlands AB - 193", "Inlands AB - 194", "Inlands AB - 30", 
"Inlands AB - 325", "Inlands AB - 65", "J A Enhörnings T AB - 325", 
"J H Munktells PF AB - 166", "J H Munktells PF AB - 236", "J H Munktells PF AB - 262", 
"J H Munktells PF AB - 349", "J H Munktells PF AB - 350", "J H Munktells PF AB - 351", 
"J H Munktells PF AB - 96", "Kalix t ind AB - 266", "Kalix t ind AB - 78", 
"Karlholms AB - 19", "Karlholms AB - 20", "Karlholms AB - 85", 
"Karlholms AB - 9", "Karlsfors B AB - 21", "Karlsfors B AB - 22", 
"Katrinedal - 23", "KatrineForss AB - 145", "KatrineForss AB - 169", 
"KatrineForss AB - 205", "KatrineForss AB - 258", "KatrineForss AB - 360", 
"KatrineForss AB - 361", "KatrineForss AB - 362", "KatrineForss AB - 363", 
"KatrineForss AB - 364", "KatrineForss AB - 365", "KatrineForss AB - 53", 
"Kohlsäters AB - 183", "Kohlsäters AB - 24", "Kohlsäters AB - 25", 
"Konga AB - 26", "KopparForss AB - 212", "KopparForss AB - 213", 
"KopparForss AB - 214", "KopparForss AB - 215", "Koppoms PF AB - 183", 
"Koppoms PF AB - 234", "Koppoms PF AB - 291", "Koppoms PF AB - 292", 
"Koppoms PF AB - 293", "Korsnäs AB - 216", "Korsnäs AB - 217", 
"Korsnäs AB - 218", "Korsnäs AB - 221", "Korsnäs AB - 222", "Korsnäs AB - 223", 
"Korsnäs AB - 224", "Korsnäs AB - 268", "Korsnäs AB - 312", "Korsnäs AB - 313", 
"Korsnäs AB - 359", "Korsnäs AB - 7", "KramForss AB - 308", "KramForss AB - 309", 
"KramForss AB - 310", "Kroppstadfors B - 15", "Kroppstadfors B - 28", 
"Lagamills AB - 227", "Lagamills AB - 251", "Lagamills AB - 252", 
"Lagerfors B - 225", "Lagerfors B - 226", "LennartsForss AB - 285", 
"LennartsForss AB - 30", "LennartsForss AB - 65", "Lessebo AB - 200", 
"Lilla Edets Pappersbruk AB - 32", "Lilla Edets Pappersbruk AB - 33", 
"Lilla Edets Pappersbruk AB - 331", "Ljungaskog AB - 282", "Långasjönäs PB - 201", 
"Långasjönäs PB - 209", "Långrörs AB - 218", "M Petersen & sön AS - 133", 
"M Petersen & sön AS - 134", "Mackmyra SFI AB - 346", "Mackmyra SFI AB - 347", 
"Marbäcks F AB - 34", "Marbäcks F AB - 35", "Marbäcks F AB - 40", 
"Marma-Långrörs AB - 159", "Marma-Långrörs AB - 217", "Marma-Långrörs AB - 218", 
"Marma-Långrörs AB - 219", "Marma-Långrörs AB - 221", "Masonite AB - 176", 
"Masonite AB - 229", "Midnäs Ind AB - 41", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 223", 
"Mo o Domsjö AB - 230", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 231", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 232", 
"Mo o Domsjö AB - 233", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 235", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 236", 
"Mo o Domsjö AB - 237", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 240", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 241", 
"Mo o Domsjö AB - 268", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 269", "Mo o Domsjö AB - 277", 
"Mo o Domsjö AB - 66", "Moälvens TS - 326", "Moälvens TS - 36", 
"Munkedals AB - 279", "Munkedals AB - 37", "Munkedals AB - 38", 
"Munkedals AB - 39", "Munksjö AB - 113", "Munksjö AB - 142", 
"Munksjö AB - 205", "Munksjö AB - 243", "Munksjö AB - 244", "Munksjö AB - 245", 
"Munksjö AB - 246", "Munksjö AB - 247", "Munksjö AB - 248", "Munksjö AB - 250", 
"Munksjö AB - 251", "Munksjö AB - 252", "Munksjö AB - 253", "Munksjö AB - 254", 
"Munksjö AB - 255", "Munksjö AB - 256", "Munksjö AB - 257", "Munksjö AB - 265", 
"Munksjö AB - 266", "Munksjö AB - 270", "Munksjö AB - 289", "Munksjö AB - 338", 
"Munksjö AB - 374", "Munksunds AB - 294", "Munksunds AB - 295", 
"Munksunds AB - 296", "Munksunds AB - 307", "Nensjö C AB - 248", 
"Nensjö C AB - 309", "Nensjö C AB - 7", "Nils Hobro - 239", "Nils Hobro - 240", 
"NissaForss AB/G Lord - 235", "NissaForss AB/G Lord - 40", "Nissaströms AB - 260", 
"Nissaströms AB - 261", "Nissaströms AB - 291", "Nordmalings Å AB - 230", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 115", "Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 199", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 200", "Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 263", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 264", "Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 265", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 266", "Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 267", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 268", "Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 269", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 270", "Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 271", 
"Norrlands Skogsägares Cellulosa AB - 311", "Nyboholms AB - 202", 
"Nyboholms AB - 210", "Nyboholms AB - 211", "Nyboholms AB - 235", 
"Nymölla AB - 42", "Nymölla AB - 43", "Nättraby B AB - 43", "Nättraby B AB - 44", 
"Ockelbo Pappf AB - 74", "Oppboga AB - 380", "Oppboga AB - 381", 
"Oppboga AB - 382", "Oskarström SFI M AB - 45", "Pilgrimsstads AB - 358", 
"Qvills B AB - 211", "Ranå B AB - 50", "Ranå B AB - 51", "Rockhammars B AB - 45", 
"Rockhammars B AB - 46", "Rockhammars B AB - 47", "Rockhammars B AB - 57", 
"Rockhammars B AB - 64", "Rockhammars B AB - 65", "Rockhammars B AB - 72", 
"Rockhammars B AB - 86", "Rällså såg O PPF - 48", "Rällså såg O PPF - 49", 
"Sandvikens C AB - 265", "Sandvikens C AB - 373", "Sannes Söners AB - 184", 
"Sannes Söners AB - 235", "Sannes Söners AB - 260", "Sannes Söners AB - 291", 
"SIAB - 333", "SIAB - 334", "SIAB - 335", "SIAB - 336", "SIAB - 337", 
"SIAB - 338", "SIAB - 339", "SIAB - 340", "SIAB - 341", "SIAB - 342", 
"Skånes C AB - 360", "Skånes C AB - 52", "Skånes C AB - 53", 
"Skånes C AB - 54", "Skönviks AB - 297", "Skönviks AB - 298", 
"Skönviks AB - 299", "Skönviks AB - 300", "SLT Group - 374", 
"SLT Group - 375", "SLT Group - 376", "Stjernfors-Ställdalen - 320", 
"Stjernfors-Ställdalen - 354", "Stjernfors-Ställdalen - 355", 
"Stjernfors-Ställdalen - 356", "Stora Kopparberg - 179", "Stora Kopparberg - 205", 
"Stora Kopparberg - 313", "Stora Kopparberg - 342", "Stora Kopparberg - 343", 
"Stora Kopparberg - 344", "Stora Kopparberg - 345", "Stora Kopparberg - 346", 
"Stora Kopparberg - 347", "Stora Kopparberg - 348", "Stora Kopparberg - 349", 
"Stora Kopparberg - 350", "Stora Kopparberg - 351", "Stora Kopparberg - 352", 
"Stora Kopparberg - 353", "Stora Kopparberg - 355", "Stora Kopparberg - 356", 
"Stora Kopparberg - 7", "Storviks SFI AB - 214", "Strömnäs B AB - 248", 
"Strömnäs B AB - 338", "Strömnäs B AB - 339", "Strömnäs B AB - 340", 
"Strömnäs B AB - 94", "Strömnäs B AB - 95", "Ströms B AB - 318", 
"Ströms B AB - 357", "Ströms B AB - 358", "Strömsfors TS - 63", 
"Sulfit AB Göta - 159", "Sulfit AB Göta - 221", "Sulfit AB Göta - 288", 
"Sunds AB - 318", "Sundsvalls C AB - 319", "Sundsvalls C AB - 320", 
"Svaneholms AB - 241", "Svaneholms AB - 274", "Svaneholms AB - 275", 
"Svaneholms AB - 276", "Svaneholms AB - 277", "Svanö AB - 274", 
"Svartviks AB - 303", "Svartviks AB - 304", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 145", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 169", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 176", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 222", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 271", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 294", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 295", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 296", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 297", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 298", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 299", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 300", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 301", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 304", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 305", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 307", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 308", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 309", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 310", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 311", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 312", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 314", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 316", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 317", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 318", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 320", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 321", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 322", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 323", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 324", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 331", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 332", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 355", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 357", 
"Svenska Cellulosa AB - 7", "Svenska Cellulosa AB - 95", "Sörstafors PB AB - 60", 
"Sörstafors PB AB - 61", "Sörstafors PB AB - 62", "Torpshammars AB - 326", 
"Torpshammars AB - 327", "Torpshammars AB - 331", "Torsviks S AB - 67", 
"Tvärfallets el för - 164", "Uddeholmsbolaget - 376", "Uddeholmsbolaget - 377", 
"Uddeholmsbolaget - 378", "Uddeholmsbolaget - 379", "Uddeholmsbolaget - 380", 
"Ungers Ind AB - 217", "Utansjö C AB - 159", "Utansjö C AB - 221", 
"Vargöns AB - 115", "Vargöns AB - 116", "Vargöns AB - 117", "Vargöns AB - 263", 
"Vikmanshytte B AB - 367", "Vivstavarvs AB - 313", "Vivstavarvs AB - 314", 
"Vivstavarvs AB - 315", "Vivstavarvs AB - 316", "Vivstavarvs AB - 345", 
"Västerviks PB AB - 367", "Västerviks PB AB - 368", "Åmotsfors PB AB - 289", 
"Åmotsfors PB AB - 290", "ÄggForss AB - 263", "Älvsborgs PF AB - 369", 
"Örebro Pappersbruks AB - 370", "Örebro Pappersbruks AB - 371", 
"Örebro Pappersbruks AB - 372", "Örvikens AB - 273"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("These Years are present", 
"Runlength", "YearSpan", "Company"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is each row an *observation*?

Comment: @SimonO101 Each row is an unique company. First column shows which years the company is present, Runlength is the number of years it is present (difference in yearspan column), and the last column is the company name:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're looking for, but if your conditions are so limited, it's pretty easy to define them as being either "1920-1920", "1920-1929", or "1929-1929".

As such, you can subset your data like this (assuming you even wanted to subset in the first place):

```
df[grepl("1920-1920|1920-1929|1929-1929", df$YearSpan), ]
df[df$YearSpan %in% c("1920-1920", "1920-1929", "1929-1929"), ]
```

both of which would yield:

```
#     These Years are present Runlength  YearSpan                      Company
# 1                      1920         1 1920-1920 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 122
# 5                      1920         1 1920-1920 AB Billingsfors-Långed - 110
# 70                     1920         1 1920-1920            Billeruds AB - 96
# 250                    1929         1 1929-1929       AB Nykvarns Bruk - 351
# 252                    1929         1 1929-1929               AB Ohs B - 102
# 253                    1929         1 1929-1929              AB Papyrus - 38
# 254                    1929         1 1929-1929         AB Robertsfors - 302
```

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve though. Posting your desired output as part of your question would be beneficial.

---

However, since you write that you "want to find the length of how many observations there is between the years", perhaps you're just looking for `table`?

```
> table(df$YearSpan)[c("1920-1920", "1920-1929", "1929-1929")]

1920-1920 1920-1929 1929-1929 
        3         0         4
```

Comment: Nice! That is exactly what I wanted. I was looking for `grepl` but table also works:) Thanks!